# Capistrano not showing errors or interrupting deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, capistrano, capistrano3

I am working on deploying my app with Capistrano, and my deploy ran successfully after first cap production deploy, skipping all the errors, migrations and missing gems.

```
INFO [b6487eaf] Finished in 0.329 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
```

Of course the server isn't working because I have a bunch of missing configs, gems, etc. But Cap says all is fine and successfully terminates my deploy!

deploy.rb:

```
lock '3.4.0'

set :application, 'myapp'
set :repo_url, 'git@github.com:name/myapp.git'

set :deploy_to, '/home/deploy/myapp'
set :deploy_user, 'deploy'

set :linked_files, fetch(:linked_files, []).push('config/database.yml', '.env')

set :linked_dirs, fetch(:linked_dirs, []).push('log', 'tmp/pids', 'tmp/cache', 'tmp/sockets', 'vendor/bundle', 'public/system', 'public/uploads')

namespace :deploy do

  desc 'Restart application'
  task :restart do
    on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
      execute :touch, release_path.join('tmp/restart.txt')
    end
  end

  after :publishing, :restart

end
```

deploy/production.rb

```
role :app, %w{deploy@123.456.78.09}
role :web, %w{deploy@123.456.78.09}
role :db, %w{deploy@123.456.78.09}

set :rails_env, :production

server '123.456.78.09', user: 'deploy', roles: %w{app db web}, primary: true

 set :ssh_options, {
   keys: %w(/Users/user/.ssh/id_rsa),
   forward_agent: true,
   auth_methods: %w(publickey password)
 }
```

Comment: Is it possible you forgot some capistrano packages for rails such as: `'capistrano/rails'` or `'capistrano/bundler'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out I have set up my Capfile wrong, forgetting the

```
require 'capistrano/rails'
```

Line. Without it capistrano simply uploaded the files without running rails-related commands